# Fatal Error when adding Custom Tab on Facebook Page

Tags: facebook, facebook-php-sdk

With Facebook SDK V5, I'm trying to develop a php script who list all my pages where I'm admin. Then the goal is to add a Custom Tab on the selected Facebook page.

The first part works well but when I'm trying to add the Custom Page, I have a Fatal Error.

I want to clarify that I already develop this king of script with SDK V4 (who works well). So my 2 facebook apps are well configured (manage_pages is ok for install and Secure URL of the Page tab is complete).

This is the lines of code who generate the Fatal Error:

```php
$addTab = $fb->post('/' . $page['id'] . '/tabs', array('app_id' => 'myappid'), $page['access_token']);
$addTab = $addTab->getGraphNode()->asArray();
print_r($addTab);
```

The contents of `$page['id']` and `$page['access_token']` are OK. When I test the Acccess Token, it's also ok.

When I execute the script and try to add the custom tab, I have this message:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookAuthenticationException' with message '(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action' in /home/web/...
```

I don't understand the problem, so any help is welcome and will be of great help to me. Thank you!

Comment: Do the pages in question have the required number of likes that is necessary to install a page tab app?

Comment: @misorude yes they are more than 2000 likes.

Comment: Are you sure page id and token actually match? (You don’t need to explicitly specify the page id in the API call btw., you can just make the request against `/me` instead - the API will automatically resolve that to the id of the page the token is for.)

Comment: When I debug token here : https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/accesstoken/ , all is OK (install app id, page id, expiration).

Comment: Yeah but does it match what `$page['id']` contains? And what happens when you just try `/me` instead?

Comment: Yes both have same value. When I try `$fb->post('/me/tabs', array('app_id' => 'myappid'), $page['access_token']);` I have the same error `(#33) This object does not exist or does not support this action`

Comment: Try the same request with the same parameters in Graph API Explorer then - if you get the same error message there, then it is not a problem specific to your code, but must be something else then.

Comment: Same error in Graph API Explorer :'(

Comment: And the user that created the page token is a “full” admin on the page, and not just some of the lesser roles? When you do a `/me/accounts` request in GAE, what does it show in “tasks” for the specific page in question?

Comment: Yes the roles are good, for all pages listed I have these:
`"tasks": [
        "ANALYZE",
        "ADVERTISE",
        "MODERATE",
        "CREATE_CONTENT",
        "MANAGE"
      ]`

Comment: And the app is not maybe already installed on the page? (Not sure if a second attempt would get _that_ error message, or something else.) If that’s not it, then I don’t know what else it could be either.

Comment: Nope, the application is not installed. Thank you for your time.